# How can I look up which dSYMs have been uploaded to Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I recently added Crashlytics support to an iOS app. I've uploaded my app's dSYMs using the `upload-symbols` script, and it reported no errors. In the Crashlytics console, however, I see that some required dSYMs are missing, but I have no way of knowing which ones. Is there a way to list which dSYMs have been uploaded, so I can figure out which ones are missing?